# How to use a path relative to my java-application in order to open the windows help viewer?

Tags: java, netbeans, awt, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to open the file `sample.chm`, when the user clicks on the help menu item. I am using NetBeans 7.01.  Both my class files and help folder are in:

```
NetBeansProjects\MyApplication\src\org\me\myapplication
```

This is the code:

```
 private void helpContentsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 File f = new File("/help/sample.chm");
  try {
      Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
 }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: \help\sample.chm doesn't exist.
```

Comment: 1) The `"/help/sample.chm"` string, when turned into a file, will point to a file object in the root of whatever drive on which it resides.  E.G.  If the code is executing from path `C:\path\to\the\app\` the file will be `C:\help\sample.chm`.  2) A deployed application will generally not be able to place or locate resources by `File` objects.  It would be better to either a) find a pure Java viewer for the type that can accept an URL formed from the application's class-path, or b) Put the resource into a 'known path' such as a sub-directory of `user.home`, then access it from there as a file.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the tutorial i followed, http://leepoint.net/notes-java/tools/netbeans/netbeans.html#packaging

Comment: checked, "help/sample.chm" also.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is thrown because the the path you've mentioned is not correct. try to give absolute path
     File f=new File("/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApplication/src/help/sample.chm");

Answer (score -1):

It should get resolved if you give the absolute path of the file as shown below:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;


public class FileOpen {
    private static void helpContentsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         File f = new File("C:/Users/compaq/Desktop/jsp.txt");// Absolute path of the file
          try {
              Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
          }
         }
}
```

Comment: absolute path? it is not a good practice, what if you generate a jar file and move it to other platforms and try to run it. probably it will not find that file in every machine and will fail. project file references should be relative so that it could easily be moved and used anywhere else. Got it?

Comment: Oh! man... I won't recommend you to hard code the absolute path in your code in such a situation. You can pass it as command line argument while you are working with jar files..